# What is the index type of const object in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typeof, keyof

I would like to define a type based on values of an Object.

For example,

```
const foo = <const>{
  'a': ['1', '2', '3', '4'],
  'b': ['5', '6', '7', '8'],
  'c': ['9', '10', '11', '12'],
};

type RandomType = typeof foo[Readonly<string>][number]; // '1' | '2' | '3' | ... | '12'
```

But TypeScript reports the following error if I use `number` as the index type

```
Type '{ readonly a: readonly ["1", "2", "3", "4"]; readonly b: readonly ["5", "6", "7", "8"]; readonly c: readonly ["9", "10", "11", "12"]; }' has no matching index signature for type 'string'.ts(2537)
```

A workaround is replacing `Readonly<string>` with `keyof typeof foo`

```
type RandomType = typeof foo[keyof typeof foo][number];
```

But it makes the statement longer and harder to read, especially if the object I use is nested within another object, like `aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd.foo`.

---

Why won't `Readonly<string>` works in the case above?

Is `keyof typeof foo` the shortest form to describe `'a' | 'b' | 'c'`? Is there any type to replace it and make the statement easier to read?

Comment: Extract alias `type Foo = typeof foo`, then use it `type RandomType = Foo[keyof Foo][number]`

Comment: `Readonly<string>` doesn't make any sense. What are you trying to describe with it?

Comment: There is no such thing as a JSON **Object**. JSON is a string notation

Comment: @AlekseyL. I am trying to describe `'a' | 'b' | 'c'` with it. I am looking for a shorter form for `keyof typeof foo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Values` utility type.

```js
const foo = {
    'a': ['1', '2', '3', '4'],
    'b': ['5', '6', '7', '8'],
    'c': ['9', '10', '11', '12'],
} as const;

type Values<T> = T[keyof T]

type RandomType = Values<typeof foo>[number];
```

Comment: Thx. It makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

> Why won't `Readonly<string>` works in the case above?

Because your object does not have a key for all possible string.

'bar' is a string, but when you access `foo['bar']` you get `undefined`, not an array of strings, so your type would not make sense.

> Is keyof typeof foo the shortest form to describe 'a' | 'b' | 'c'? Is there any type to replace it and make the statement easier to read?

You can assign it to an intermediate type if you need to use it in different places:

```
type FooKeys = keyof typeof foo
type RandomType = typeof foo[FooKeys][number];
```